# FME Use Output of reader in another reader

Tags: fme-form

I have a ESRI geodatabase reader to read input table and i am using where clause to limit data based on date. write now i am using the user parameter to ask user latest date for input table. and then i am writing it to output table.

I want to check the maximum date in output table and based on that i want to give that maximum date as an input to input table reader so that every time my FME run user do not have to manually enter maximum date.

I have searched for this and now i have the maximum date as i have added the output layer as a reader and i am using Statistics Calculator to get maximum value.

Now How can i use that maximum value as an input to where clause of input table reader ? There seem to be no way of connecting anything to reader.

Comment: have you tried the featurereader transformer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [**FeatureReader**](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/featurereader.htm) transformer will do what you want. It behaves like a normal reader, but you can pass in other features/attributes which can go into your where clause.

I suggest you get the information you want from the StatisticsCalculator and pass a single feature from it. Then, pass that single feature into the FeatureReader.

If you pass multiple features into the FeatureReader it will run it for each feature.

Comment: a sorter-by-date and sampler (first 1 only) will work a lot faster than a statisticscalculator, that one is quite the resource hog.

Comment: Good point and it's definitely the way to go. OP is already using a StatisticsCalculator which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: Yes i am now using it. But its taking too much time. The geodatabase from which i am reading the input table contains more then thirty feature classes. I am choosing my input featureclass. and when i press ok the "Reading dataset" box is taking too much time.

@Borgh Thanks I will switch to this approach definitely this will be faster